# error in Firebase Authentication in Facebook Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

error in Firebase Authentication in Facebook Javascript

this error in pic

[image]

this code

```
function signin(){
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('user_birthday,email');
firebase.auth().useDeviceLanguage(); 
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result){
   var token = result.credential.accessToken;
   document.querySelector("#signout").style.display="block";
   console.log(user);
   var user=result.user;
   console.log(user.email);
   var userimage=document.querySelector("#user-image");

   var userpic=document.createElement("img");
   userpic.src=user.photoURL;
   userimage.append(userpic);

   var useremail=document.querySelector("#user-email");
   useremail.innerHTML=user.email;

});
```

}

Comment: maybe you should try to use it from another device/network

Comment: Please include all needed information in the post (errors, logs, code, etc), not in images or pastebins.